# Is a system of free spinless fermions always critical?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, critical-phenomena

Consider a system of free spinless fermions, whose Hamiltonian can be written as
$$
H = \sum_{i,j}h_{ij}a_i^\dagger a_j-\lambda\sum_i a^\dagger_i a_i
$$
with $h_{ij}=h_{ji}^*$ scalars and $a_i^\dagger$ ($1\le i\le N$) a set of fermionic creation operators. Is such a system *always* quantum critical (in the sense that it can be described by a 2-D conformal field theory (CFT) at low energies) for $\lambda$ in a certain range (at least when the corresponding 
dispersion relation is, e.g., monotonic in the momentum)? Any references to textbooks or professional papers would be most welcome! I am also a bit confused about the definition of "quantum critical" itself, since some authors seem to equate it to "gapless", whereas others require that the system be conformal invariant, and thus desirable by a 2-D CFT at low energies. Would somebody care to comment on this too?

Comment: Conformal invariance implies scale invariance, and scale invariance either means complete masslessness or continuous mass spectrum, i.e. a gapless system either way. So the notion of "quantum critical" as "conformally invariant" is slightly stronger than that as "gapless" (since scale invariance does not always imply conformal invariance).

Answer (score 2):

No. A system of spinless fermions can be gapped and there are plenty examples. For example, at half filling there can be a charge-density wave order. The question is more interesting if you add additional symmetries. The Hamiltonian you write preserves the U(1) fermion number. If furthermore one requires translation symmetry and if the filling (i.e. average number of fermions per unit cell) is fractional, then it is guaranteed that the system is gapless. However, it is gapless in the sense of having a Fermi sea. Most people would not call a Fermi liquid "quantum critical" since it lacks scale invariance. If you ask for some robust critical metal, one example I can think of is spinless fermions on a hexagonal lattice (i.e. graphene) at half-filling, assuming the Hamiltonian preserving all space group symmetries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I was actually interested in a translationally invariant system, in which $h(i,j)=h(|i-j|)$ (I am also assuming periodic boundary conditions). In this case you can diagonalize the Hamiltonian by a discrete Fourier transform. Suppose that the dispersion function $E$ (the Fourier transform of $h$)  is monotonic on $[0,\pi]$, and that the chemical potential $\lambda$ belongs to $(0,E(\pi))$. If I am interpreting your answer correctly, not even in this situation it is guaranteed that the system is described (at least at low energies) by a 2-D CFT. Is that right?

Comment: I would not call such a state 2-D CFT, because the system is clearly non-relativisitic (i.e. no emergent Lorentz symmetry), and there is a characteristic length/momentum scale, which is the size of the Fermi surface. Low-energy excitations of the state are particle-hole excitations near the Fermi surface.